# Sanitize string to using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, sanitization

I basically want to use tel tag to make a phone call.

```
<a class="callButton" href="tel: {{phoneno}}"></a>
```

I am using $compileProvider to  remove unsafe tag which comes by default, It works perfectly fine post 1.0.4v of angularjs. However below this version it doesnt work. Can anyone suggest how to implement this feature using angular version 1.0.4 or below?

Here is the sanitizing code which I am using in js file

```
app.config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
    $compileProvider.urlSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|tel):/);
}
```

Assume I have already defined app variable.

P.S. This is an enhancement for particular app which basically works below 1.0.4v

Thanks

Comment: Did you try using the sanitize plugin for angularjs?

Comment: I just did that and it works. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your scripts after angular is loaded.

I asume your on 1.1.5, but change to whatever you need the version to be.
http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular-sanitize.min.js

Example:

```
sanitizeSomething = function(string) {
    return $sanitize(string);
};

sanitizedString = sanitizeSomething(string);
```